# What is the correct pathway for Django OTP body message?

Tags: python, html, django, debugging, settings

I'm doing a Django project and I'm at where I want to have a custom OTP email to the users. I have tried everything I could think of to have the OTP email not just display the OTP code but also the HTML but it just displays the path of "text"

I have read the docs but couldn't find much help.

settings.py:

```
text = 'Templates/email.txt'
html = 'Templates/email.html'
#OTP settings
OTP_EMAIL_SENDER=""
OTP_EMAIL_SUBJECT="Verification Code"
OTP_EMAIL_TOKEN_TEMPLATE=text
OTP_EMAIL_BODY_TEMPLATE=text
OTP_EMAIL_BODY_TEMPLATE_PATH=html
OTP_EMAIL_TOKEN_VALIDITY=300
```

email.html:

```
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#fdfbf0" style="padding:25px">
        <p style="margin: 0;">
            <!--the safe parameter allows us to generate html. always make sure you are passing valid html markup to the email body-->
            {{email_body|safe}}
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

email.txt:

```
{{email_body}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the same problem where I needed to use my customized email template. The code responsible for sending email is in [django_otp.plugins.otp_email.models.py](https://github.com/django-otp/django-otp/blob/d9095d9a57e4a1086af275c5eebdd3e1f84bb7d9/src/django_otp/plugins/otp_email/models.py) file. You can see the *generate_challenge()* in *EmailDevice* Model class. I solved it by adding *html_message* parameter in *send_mail()* as follow:

django_otp.plugins.otp_email.models.py
...

```
send_mail(settings.OTP_EMAIL_SUBJECT,
      strip_tags(body),
      settings.OTP_EMAIL_SENDER,
      [self.email or self.user.email],
      html_message=body)

      ...
```

My use-case was different so, I forked the original [django-otp](https://github.com/django-otp/django-otp/) package and then install it into my docker environment.

You can also do this by writing your own Device. Here's the link to [Extending Django-OTP](https://django-otp-official.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extend.html) documentation.