# Customize django-otp email template

Tags: django, templates, customization

I'm doing two-factor authentication (2FA) in my Django app and using *[django-otp](https://django-otp-official.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)* package. I want to send my custom email to users. I followed the official documentation and added my custom settings as follow:

```
# django-otp template
OTP_EMAIL_SUBJECT = _('Please confirm your login attempt')
OTP_EMAIL_BODY_TEMPLATE_PATH = 'account/email/login_confirmation_otp.html'
```

The above settings are working and it's sending the email in text/plain content type but I want text/html content type.

The following code is sending the email:

```
def generate_challenge(self, extra_context=None):
    """
    Generates a random token and emails it to the user.

    :param extra_context: Additional context variables for rendering the
        email template.
    :type extra_context: dict

    """
    self.generate_token(valid_secs=settings.OTP_EMAIL_TOKEN_VALIDITY)

    context = {'token': self.token, **(extra_context or {})}
    if settings.OTP_EMAIL_BODY_TEMPLATE:
        body = Template(settings.OTP_EMAIL_BODY_TEMPLATE).render(Context(context))
    else:
        body = get_template(settings.OTP_EMAIL_BODY_TEMPLATE_PATH).render(context)

    send_mail(settings.OTP_EMAIL_SUBJECT,
              body,
              settings.OTP_EMAIL_SENDER,
              [self.email or self.user.email])

    message = "sent by email"

    return message
```

in [django_otp/plugins/otp_email/models.py](https://github.com/django-otp/django-otp/blob/d9095d9a57e4a1086af275c5eebdd3e1f84bb7d9/src/django_otp/plugins/otp_email/models.py). I want to override generate_challenge() function and add *html_message* in *send_email()* function but don't know how to do it?

Comment: I solved it and here I posted my answer. [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67826769/what-is-the-correct-pathway-for-django-otp-body-message/71065399#71065399)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to make it. The code responsible for sending email is in [django_otp.plugins.otp_email.models.py](https://github.com/django-otp/django-otp/blob/d9095d9a57e4a1086af275c5eebdd3e1f84bb7d9/src/django_otp/plugins/otp_email/models.py) file. You can see the *generate_challenge()* in the *EmailDevice* Model class. I solved it by adding *html_message* parameter in *send_mail()* as follow:

django_otp.plugins.otp_email.models.py
...

```
send_mail(settings.OTP_EMAIL_SUBJECT,
      strip_tags(body),
      settings.OTP_EMAIL_SENDER,
      [self.email or self.user.email],
      html_message=body)

      ...
```

My use-case was different so, I forked the original [django-otp](https://github.com/django-otp/django-otp/) package and then use it.

You can also do this by writing your own Device. Here's the link to [Extending Django-OTP](https://django-otp-official.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extend.html) documentation.